# Erro de sintaxe "Unexpected tag name" no Symfony2/Twig

Tags: php, symfony-2, twig

Minha `list` tem o código abaixo:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
{% for posts in post %}
    <article>
        <h2>
            {% post.titulo %}
        </h2>
        <div class="content">
            {% post.conteudo %}
       </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

mas ao executar, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Unexpected tag name "post" (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 3) in /home/jose/Downloads/projetos/Symfony/src/LearnSF/Bundle/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Post/list.html.twig at line 5

Como consertar?

Comment: * posts é um array que vem do controller.
* post é a variável da pagina que deveria ser exibina no loop, e não está declarada na pagina.

Comment: verifique se a variável posts não se encontra vazia, sem nenhum conteúdo.

Comment: no symfony profiler > doctrine, expandindo as queries, mostra uma linha como resultado (exatamente o numero de registros que tenho no banco de dados). Alguma outra alternativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte maneira

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
    <article>
        <h2>
            {{ post.titulo }}
        </h2>
        <div class="content">
            {{ post.conteudo }}
       </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

A marcação `{% %}` é para "faça alguma coisa" e a marcação `{{ }}` é "mostre alguma coisa". O seu `for` está invertido, o `for` correto é assim: `{% for item in lista %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Obrigado Fábio. Funcionou direitinho aqui. o problema realmente estava marcação de exibição, tem que ser {{}}.